# Loading successive select boxes on startup with javascript

Tags: javascript, select, onload

I am trying to populate select boxes from javascript at start up, with each one depending on the previous one.

In HTML code I have

```
<body onload="start_up()">  
<span id="FirstList">xxxxxxx</span>  
<span id="SecondList">xxxxxxx</span>
```

Javascript code is

```
function start_up()
{
 load_select('','Type1')
 load_select(document.getElementById('select_first').value,'Type2')
}

function load_select(argument,code)
{
   xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (xmlhttp==null)
       {
          alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
          return;
       }
   var url="getdropdown.php";
   url=url+"?q="+code+argument;
   url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();  // this is needed to make sure its not loading a cached version
 last_http_type=code;
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
   xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
             if (last_http_type=="Type1")                      
                document.getElementById("FirstList").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             else if (last_http_type=="Type2")
               document.getElementById("SecondList").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             else if (last_http_type=="Type3")
               document.getElementById("OutputTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             else if (last_http_type=="Type4")
               document.getElementById("OutputTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             last_http_type="cleared";      
        }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  return new XMLHttpRequest();   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   // code for IE6, IE5
return null;
}
```

The select boxes are named select_first and select_second when their code is generated in php.

This works fine for the first one, but the second load_select fails due to it not knowing about select_first. I was assuming that its done sequentially and thus, by the time it reaches the statement, should know about the first drop down. (Note that the code above is simplified a little bit to illustrate the problem, the second argument of load_select determines the exact SQL call, also stateChanged is slightly more complicated since it needs to know which load_select was called. However, they all work fine by themselves, its the multiple load at startup which fails.)

Comment: Can you please provide the code of start_up() and load_select() functions?

Comment: start_up only contains the 2 load_select lines above; load_select is
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   var url="getdropdown.php";
   url=url+"?q="+code+argument;
   url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();  // this is needed to make sure its not loading a cached version
  last_http_type=code;
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
   xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
which I believe is the standard way to get data from php/sql

Comment: um, can you please put this into question text with some formatting? :)

Comment: A little bit to less code, but I think you're executing the second call before the first ajax call is finished. You should executed the second on in the `stateChanged()`.

Comment: Final note (problem solved succesfully) to anyone using this code above. You want to use xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false) rather than ,true since this causes asynchronous calls where the last_type_http may be messed up.

Comment: Possibly need this in a new question, but for some reason this is not very browser robust. It works fine in IE, it only loads the first box in Chrome and it doesnt even load the first one in Firefox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are making two consecutive AJAX calls and try to tie the execution of second one to the result of the first one? This doesn't work that way, because first A letter in AJAX means Asynchronous, meaning "okay, guys, I'll go fetch that url but you can go on without me". So javascript fires first request and then goes further without waiting for it to return something.

If you want to run second request only after successful execution of the first one, then you'll need to use callbacks and `onSuccess()` event.

To make it shorter, put the second call in the `stateChanged()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You should write your javascript separate from your html. 
So your page startup event should be

```
window.onload = function() {
    ....
    }
 or with jquery:
 $(function() { 
  ....
 });
```

So there you can put your other functions and code. And here would be a excellent to use JQuery. Look for example [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/). It would propably solve your problems much faster than writing ajax from scratch.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.